# Find duplicates and create bands in Excel

Tags: excel-formula, duplicates, unique, countif

I am trying to create buckets based on the number of times id is repeated using an Excel formula

I have the following data format

```
  ID
 101
 200
 100
 100
 125
 200
```

I am trying to achieve the following

```
  1        2              /*Unique Ids*/
  2        2              /*Ids with two repetitions */
  3        0
```

This is basically removing the duplicate IDs and finding the number of repetitions for each id. I would like to do this is in a single cell using Excel formulas

All that I did was copy these IDs to another sheet, remove duplicates, use `COUNTIF` to count the number of occurrences, and use that to create my buckets.

Thanks

Comment: Write it so it's not in a single cell and do an array to merge it

Answer (score 1):

If one has the dynamic array formula put this in the first cell:

```
=CHOOSE({1,2},SEQUENCE(3),INDEX(FREQUENCY(COUNTIF(A2:A7,A2:A7),SEQUENCE(3))/SEQUENCE(3),SEQUENCE(3)))
```

[image]

With the new LET() formula:

```
=LET(seq,{1;2;3},rng,A2:A7,CHOOSE({1,2},seq,INDEX(FREQUENCY(COUNTIF(rng,rng),seq)/seq,seq)))
```

---

If not then use put this array formula in the first cell:

```
=CHOOSE(COLUMN(A1),ROW(A1),INDEX(FREQUENCY(COUNTIF($A$2:$A$7,$A$2:$A$7),{1;2;3})/{1;2;3},ROW(A1)))
```

Confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter instead of Enter and copy over one column and down three rows.

[image]

Comment: I am getting 1,2,3 in column F instead of 2,2,0

Comment: which formula are you using.  If the last one, you put it in one cell, hit ctrl-shift-enter then drag over one column and down two.  @ckp